# File removeEditor issue (DriveApp)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an issue trying to remove active user editor from a file.
When I try the follwing code it works just fine :

```
function testOwner() {
   var theFile = DriveApp.createFile('New Text File', 'Hello, world!');
   theFile.setOwner('anemail@mydomain.fr');
   theFile.removeEditor(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

But when I'm using the 'makeCopy' method I get a message error that stops the script even if the editor has been removed. Here is the code :

```
function testOwner2() {
   var template = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID);
   var theFile = template.makeCopy('Name');
   theFile.setOwner('anemail@mydomain.fr');
   theFile.removeEditor(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

The error message on the removeEditor line : 'Impossible de trouver l'élément correspondant à cet identifiant. Vous n'êtes peut-être pas autorisé à y accéder.' meaning 'Couldn't find any element matching  this ID. Maybe you are not authorized to access it'

I didn't find any question on this. Is is a known issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

when you `.makeCopy()`, all the editors get removed for the new file.

in addition to help debug, use Logger some and view the logs...

```js
function testOwner2() {
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID);
  var theFile = template.makeCopy('Name');
  theFile.setOwner('anemail@mydomain.fr');

  var editors = theFile.getEditors();
  for ( var i in editors ) { Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail()); }
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  theFile.removeEditor(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Try `.getEffectiveUser()` instead of `.getActiveUser()` as that's typically a cause of unexpected results as well.

Comment: Thanks for that but getEffectiveUser doesn't change the issue

Answer (score 0):

*This is to be considered as a comment, just taking a bit more place than a regular one.*

There seems to be an issue with the code suggested in the other answer : You just can't remove yourself as an editor (and you automatically become an editor when you set the ownership to another user) when you are not the owner of the copied file anymore... you will get just the same error message.

The first code snippet you give that creates a file should follow the same logic but - as I learned today (thanks for that) - it does not and I really don't know why.

*( I hope someone "better informed" will explain... )*

I guess the only solution (at least that I can imagine using a script) if you don't want to be an editor of the copy would be to integrate a small script in your template (that would be copied in the copy) to create a menu allowing the new user to call a function that would remove you as an editor.

Or more simply after all, explain how to do it from the Drive Ui itself ;-)

Comment: I thought first but as the first code was ok I believed it was possible.
My app is used by operators that generates files from a template filled by new data that will be later on used by other people that should become the only editors.
Too bad it's not possible.
Thanks for your confirmation anyway.
And yes the behavior is anyhow surprising ...

Comment: Maybe you could try using extended Drive Service , see [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Permissions) and doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

Comment: Sorry I've missed your suggestion. I'll try that. Thanks